# AngularJS page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page which makes an API call to retrieve data and display it. Everything appears to work fine when navigating from home to this page, but if I press F5 the data is lost and only the bindings are shown `{{first_name}}`

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('examinersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://shielded-reaches-93856.herokuapp.com/v1/examiners'
       }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.examiners = data;
       }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('There was an error getting the data');
       });
   });
});
```

It seems bizarre that the http request is being made only on the initial page load, and not when a refresh happens. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen all the time ? Try to test in private browsing (like incognito in chrome). Also add some console.log in your controller and investigate  what happens when you press F5.

Comment: I don't see scope variable 'first_name' in your controller

Comment: when I hit F5 and put a console.log outside of the http request it will show up, but nothing inside the http request happens. the expression would actually be {{examiners.first_name}}.

Comment: actually, trying again it looks like nothing in my controller gets run when I hit F5, only when I navigate to that page from somewhere else in the app (like the home page). I am using routing in this app if that changes anything...

Comment: Sometimes your rest api data may be cached in the browser and it would not loaded again... its a quite tricky

Comment: @AlixOhrt Do you have configured route path which is registered with `examinersCtrl` controller?

Comment: yes, it is

                    .when('/examiners', {
                        templateUrl : 'app/components/examiners/examinersListView.html',
                        controller  : 'examinersCtrl'
                    })

Comment: hmm...it appears that when I first navigate from home to examiners it doesn't load, but if I go back to home then back to examiners it works - I must be missing something...

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in a fiddle?

Comment: This is interesting. You can fix it by adding your http request in scope function and calling it with ng-init, but I don't know if that is clean enough.